# How to prevent triggered all forms inside a map at the same time using react hook form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

How to handle multiple forms in .map in reactjs using react-hook-form? the problem is when I click the button all forms get triggered and show errors like in this image [Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z94zQ.png) , and the thing is I want every form be separate from each other and activate just when I click a button and obtain the data corresponding

```js
{Order.orderDetails.map((item, index) => (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit2(ChangeProductStatus)}>
     <div className="form-control mb-5">
        <label className="text-medium font-semibold">Change Status Order</label>
          <select {...register2('productStatus', {required: ' Campo Requerido'})} className={(errors2.productStatus && ' select-error ') + ' select select-bordered  '}>
             <option value="Pendiente">Pending</option>
              <option value="Enviado">Sended</option>
         </select>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" onClick={() => validate(item.idOrderDetail)} className="btn btn-block  mb-5 normal-case">
              Save
      </button>
</form>
))}
```

Comment: try adding a key={index} on form.

Comment: breifly can you desicribe your implementation inside this function:
handleSubmit2(ChangeProductStatus)

Answer (score 0):

I think the map is correct my guess is that when you use  `onSubmit={handleSubmit2(ChangeProductStatus)}` you are executing the function so I think you need to change to a function similar to the one for onClick. Something like:

```
<form onSubmit={() => handleSubmit2(ChangeProductStatus)}>
```

Just in case that you don't want to refresh the page after submit you can change the button type to 'button' instead of 'submit'